# how get Client Ip Address In Silver Light

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-5.0

Whatever I tried I could not get the IP address of the client in the silver light. Can you help?
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Arer you looking for the public ip or the local ip?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried getting it through HttpContext like below?

```
IpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

see this [link](http://scottstoecker.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/recording-the-ip-address-from-silverlight/) for more info, note that you can only get the client's public ip if you're over the internet, not the private ip

Comment: hi Jason. thanks for Your Help , But This Code Return Ip Address IN Web Application, My Problem Is In Silver Light.

Comment: @FatalMan sorry, it's been a long while since I last touched SL, don't really recall how we did it back then.  It doesn't look like there is a direct way, there is an indirect way however, take a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/402a75cb-13c6-4168-956b-a6e0d87e78e7/, the second reply, by *codebased* should do the trick